# How to determine correlation between two 2D arrays?

Tags: matlab, statistics, data-analysis, correlation

I am trying to find a correlation between two 2D arrays. These arrays represent the characteristics of the system based on two parameters: voltage and magnetic field. Essentially, I want to determine if there is any correlation between changes in one matrix compared to the other.

The size of each matrix is 6x6. What would be the most effective approach to accomplish this?

I attempted to use MATLAB's xcorr2 function, but I encountered difficulties in interpreting the results since the resulting matrix is larger than the input matrices.

Comment: The documentation explains the size output in the first part. Are you struggling with that part?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To find the correlation between changes in one matrix compared to the other matrix, you can use MATLAB's *corr2()* function. The *corr2()* function calculates the correlation coefficient between two matrices, taking into account their mean and standard deviation.

```
correlation = corr2(mat1, mat2);
```

The resulting correlation coefficient will be a single scalar value between -1 and 1. A positive value close to 1 indicates a strong positive correlation, a negative value close to -1 indicates a strong negative correlation, and a value close to 0 indicates no correlation.

The *xcorr2()* function is used for calculating the 2D cross-correlation between two matrices and is not suitable for calculating correlation coefficients between matrices representing different parameters.